# Static variables initialised using static variables are not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, static-variables

If I have an static variable (*let's say foo*) that has its value inherited from another static variable and later I change the value of that other static variable then try to access foo, it still gives the old value that it was initialised with.

I have a file **endpoints.dart** with following code

```
class EndPoints {

  static String baseUrl = "someurl.com/";

  static String place = baseUrl + "api/v1/place";

}
```

here if I change the **baseUrl** in any other file and print it like

```
onPressed () {
 
 print(EndPoints.place);
 //prints someurl.com/api/v1/place

 EndPoint.baseUrl = "changedurl.com/";

 print("${EndPoints.baseUrl}");
 //prints changedurl.com/

 print("${EndPoints.place}");
  //still prints someurl.com/api/v1/place
}
```

My concern is why `static String place = baseUrl + "api/v1/place"`  not taking the updated `baseUrl` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static member `place` will not be recalculated when changing `baseUrl`. You can define a custom getter function like this:

```
class EndPoints {
  static String baseUrl = "someurl.com/";
  static String get place => baseUrl + "api/v1/place";
}
```

With this change your code will output the `place` with the updated value. Also, there is a typo in your code, `EndPoint.baseUrl` should be `EndPoints.baseUrl`.

Comment: That solved the issue. Thanks :) also I changed the baseUrl to a getter to be on safe side.

Answer (score 1):

You change the value of `baseUrl`, you don't touch the `place`. You can try to write a setter:

```
void setBaseUrl(String value) {
   this.baseUrl = value;
   this.place = baseUrl + "api/v1/place";
}
```